# Where can I get the newest "Setting Up a Dev Environment" for Docker?

Tags: docker

I find a [Setting Up a Dev Environment](https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/contributing/devenvironment/) document for `Docker 1.5`. Since I am not sure whether it is still applicable for current `Docker`, I hang out on https://docs.docker.com and try to find some newer one.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a newer document, so I just wonder whether there is newest "Setting Up a Dev Environment" document. If it does have, where can I find it?

Comment: The [help/on-topic] says *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. It applies to finding and linking documentation as well.

Comment: @KenWhite The OP is not asking for a recommendation or link at large, but rather asks about revisions of documentation s/he found already. In my reading, the question is as much *on* topic here at SO as, for example, [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) which happens to be a still-active and highly-upvoted topic.

Comment: @dxiv: That there is a still-active and highly-upvoted topic does not automatically make a similar question acceptable. What is relevant is the guidelines that are in place *at the time the question is asked*, and the current guidelines include the restriction I quoted above. See for yourself - click the link I provided. If you look, you can also find a highly-upvoted and still-active question related to a list of books for C/C++, but a new question asking for book recommendations for any topic is not acceptable.